# Python AWS Lambda's event body returning string instead of my json object

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Invocation code

```
import requests
import json
# Create a new resource
data_object = {'key1':'testing'}
response = requests.post('https://fakeurl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/My_Test_Event_Lambda', data=data_object)

print(response._content.decode())
```

Lambda Code

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': json.dumps(event['body'])
            }
```

The response I get from invocation is `"key1=testing"`
I don't care so much about the response but i want the lambda function to be able to handle my data passed as json not a string. Example: I want to be able to say event['body']['key1'] and have it return "testing"

Currently API gateways being used as lambda proxy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `event['body']` you received is a string. You need to parse that from JSON into a dict with:

```
d = json.loads(event['body'])
```

Then you can return that dict as the body in your response, if you want, via:

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps(d)
}
```

As it stands, you're just managing strings.

Comment: Hmmm I'm getting a key error when i use your code. `{
  "errorMessage": "'body'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 4, in lambda_handler\n    d = json.loads(event['body'])\n"
  ]
}`

Comment: Are you using Lambda Proxy integration in API Gateway?"

Comment: Yea i'm using the proxy integration `Type: LAMBDA_PROXY` is displayed in Integration Request

Comment: Did you debug log `event` to see what's in it? I assumed this was already working to retrieve the body, because your original code uses it.

Comment: Yes, the body is there. Which is why it doesn't make any sense to me that it's a key error. I can return event['body'] and have it return the string representation of the body. for example this works    return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(event["body"])
        }

Comment: Because the body is not actually JSON, perhaps? It's just key=value when it should be {"key":"value"} (assuming you actually meant to pass JSON over the interface).

Comment: Aha you're correct good sir! I forgot to do json.dumps(data_object) in my invoker. Tyvm